Intel ubuntu 22.04 server for intel skylake
Does ubuntu 22.04 server (kernel 5.15)support Intel® HD Graphics 530 of intel skylake?

Running Kubuntu desktop on Info: quad core Intel Core i5-6500 [MCP] speed (MHz): avg: 799
min/max: 800/3600
Graphics:
Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 driver: i915 v: kernel  Currently using 24.04, but used 22.04 Kubuntu desktop for two years.  Desktop uses all the same kernel & drivers as server.
